# How to repair warped sliding door frame?

Tags: sliding-glass-door

I've got a south-facing sliding door, the frame/track has warped stopping the screen from closing. I've seen replacement tracks, but the issue seems to be that the channel the track should ride in is too warped for a track to sit in cleanly. I was thinking about just trying to cut away some of the warped channel to get the track to lie down.

Anyone know of a way to repair this short of replacing the whole door frame? Any big drawbacks (other than appearance) to cutting away some of the warped portion just to get the track to lie down properly?

Overhead view:
[image: Warped Track]

Side View after cutting away part of warped piece, also bows upward:
[image: Side view, cut away]

Comment: I would first pull the track and clean it out. The deviation of the frame and track will cause problems and cutting away at the structure may end up causing damage that might require a new door all together.

Comment: And perhaps what the track is sitting on is damaged (wood rot?).

Comment: @EdBeal I cleaned it up after pictures, but the track itself is fine, just the channel it rests in, which I believe is the door frame itself, I think you're correct, just hunting for alternatives.

Comment: I'd probably try to bend it back into shape with some crowbars and my ballpene hammer. 
 After about an hour or two, run to the store for a new door.

Comment: @GaryBak That sounds about right.

Answer (score 1):

To me, “a warped frame” means twisted. In order to “fix” a twisted frame, you’ll need to 1) remove the track (threshold), 2) clean the track and where it’s placed, 3) straighten the track, and 4) re-secure the track to its correct position.

Straightening the track could be the most difficult. I’d try heating the track so you can twist it back to it’s original shape. I think a tool like an electricians conduit bender will work. (We use it to heat and bend Trex Decking too.) It looks like this and you could put the “warped” end of the frame into it...

https://jet.com/product/Greenlee-PVC-HeaterBender/1519c3795e4b4943bccec436d81b0447?jcmp=pla:ggl:nj_roc_gen_appliances_a1:appliances_heating_cooling_air_quality_space_heaters_a1:na:PLA_1062463102_53743929562_pla-306111780120_m:na:na:na:2PLA15&pid=kenshoo_int&c=1062463102&is_retargeting=true&clickid=7f0505b1-7b91-4390-9fd6-468b0e8922f7&kclid=7f0505b1-7b91-4390-9fd6-468b0e8922f7&gclid=CjwKCAjw54fdBRBbEiwAW28S9sAKKhrHWzpb6aTbi4bOTQiwt6dy6WvLDGMN5IDvVVJWvS0hC-ItIhoCvVkQAvD_BwE

After it’s heated, you could remove any bumps or twists in the frame before you reinstall it. (You may need to drill a few extra holes so you can add a some screws to keep it aligned until it cools.)

To keep the threshold watertight, I’d install flashing under the threshold and set it in sealant.

BTW, don’t over heat the frame or it will flop around like a piece of spaghetti and you’ll never get it back to it’s original shape.

Comment: I agree a heated blanket may do the job but after looking at the side view it looks like the frame is sagging possibly rotted wood under the frame is the root cause that will need to be repaired first then heating and straightening the frame to keep it from cracking on the repaired now level suffice.+

Comment: @EdBeal Oh, yes...having a good solid backing to secure the frame into will be critical.

Answer (score 1):

Here what I think happens. Door leads to deck, on heavy downpour deck floods and water works its way under door & frame. The wood swells and pushes door & frame out.

Now screen doesn't work because frame and fixed glass door has been pushed out.

The only solution is remove sliding glass door frame, re-position and reinstall.

I am pretty sure this is the problem with the door I have. Wood may or may not be rotted but I am pretty sure the wood has warped from occasional moisture.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

As Ed said, the cause of your warping seems to be due to your rotting of your `sill support` and/or `bottom plate`.  This site already has excellent answers on how to address rotting that I will highlight:

1. You really need [to address the source of the water](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/119437/18575) that is causing the rot, else you'll likely end up with more to repair in a few years.
2. Once you've addressed your source, you can either replace the wood or [use an epoxy resin to fix the existing piece](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/125135/18575).  I'd probably remove and straighten (or replace) the track as Lee suggested during this step, but you might be able to get away with just shimming it back into place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, vinyl doesn't rot though, right? Pretty sure it's just warped from age/sun exposure. The first picture shows how the vinyl is warped outward, no apparent rot that would explain that in the wood underneath.

Comment: @HartCO Vinyl isn't what's suppose to be providing the structural shape, for your door.  You're `sill support` or `bottom plate` are almost certainly not vinyl, and are likely compromised.